# Webscraping on html function parameter and export to csv

Tags: web-scraping

```
<div class="readmore">
     <a href="" onclick="updateDetailModal({name&quot;:&quot;Company Name 1&quot;,&quot;website&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/hello.com.sg\/&quot;,&quot;phone&quot;:&quot;65 8123 4567&quot;,&quot;email&quot;:&quot;hello@gmail.com.sg&quot;})" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">More
     </a>
</div>
```

Hi I'm looking to web scrape the following so that I can get it in a .csv file in this format`<br>`

Company Name | Website Url | Phone | Email -> 1st Row
Company Name 1 | https://hello.com.sg/ | 81234567 | hello@gmail.com -> 2nd Row
Company Name 2 | https://hello2.com.sg/ | 87654321 | hello2@gmail.com -> Subsequent rows for all links

Is there a way to use regex to get the individual fields and export them to a CSV file? I've been trying python and beautiful soup but I only know how to export using `class` or `id`. Not sure how to do it for function parameters.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

To extract the information you are looking for you need not just beautifulsoup (or lxml), but also json and a bit of string manipulation.

Assuming your html looks like this:

```
modal = """<div class="readmore">
     <a href="" onclick="updateDetailModal({&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Company Name 1&quot;,&quot;website&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/hello.com.sg\/&quot;,&quot;phone&quot;:&quot;65 8123 4567&quot;,&quot;email&quot;:&quot;hello@gmail.com.sg&quot;})" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">More
     </a>
     <a href="" onclick="updateDetailModal({&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Company Name 2&quot;,&quot;website&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/hello2.com.sg\/&quot;,&quot;phone&quot;:&quot;87654321&quot;,&quot;email&quot;:&quot;hello2@gmail.com.sg&quot;})" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">More
     </a>
</div>"""
```

Then:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json

soup = bs(modal,"lxml")

infos = soup.select('a')
companies = []
for info in infos:    
    target = info.attrs['onclick'].split('(')[1].split(')')[0]
    data = json.loads(target)
    companies.extend([[v for v in data.values()]])
```

Your data is now in the `companies` list:

```
for co in companies:
    print(co)
```

Output:

```
['Company Name 1', 'https://hello.com.sg/', '65 8123 4567', 'hello@gmail.com.sg']
['Company Name 2', 'https://hello2.com.sg/', '87654321', 'hello2@gmail.com.sg']
```

From here you write it to csv using standard methods.